# Getting ScriptHandlerFactory handler

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services, routes

Is there any way to call System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory class GetHandler method which return IHttpHandler type object. I know ScriptHandlerFactory is an internal class but is therey any other way from where I can get it? The reason I am saying is because I want to route my .asmx paths and routing needs this type of code:

```
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
{
   return new WebServiceHandlerFactory().GetHandler(HttpContext.Current,
        "*",
        _VirtualPath,
        HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(_VirtualPath));
   }
}
```

Above "WebServiceHandlerFactory" is used but I want to use ScriptHandlerFactory only since I want to make use of jquery ajax calls too. I will be calling the asmx methods via jquery ajax calls. Can you help me in doing so?

Comment: try inheriting from IHttpHandlerFactory?  then you can do something like public virtual IHttpHandler GetHandler(HttpContext context, String
requestType, String url, String pathTranslated) {  return (IHttpHandler)aspxPage; }

Comment: Dmitry, you can't inherit an interface. You can only implement it. Unfortunately, ASP.NET made a lot of classes internal, which is a huge pain. Like in my instance (see my answer), I needed the default functionality, but then I needed to be able to pass it to an IoC provider to build-up the properties. I couldn't do that without resorting to reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowed from Spring.Net. I use it to access the `SimpleHttpHandler` because I use IoC to create `HttpHandler`s.

**Edit:** [This is the code](https://anonsvn.springframework.org/svn/spring-net/branches/nhibernate_configuration_schema/src/Spring/Spring.Web/Web/Support/AbstractHandlerFactory.cs) that I used to figure out how to do it. Obviously, it requires **full trust**, and I didn't like this hack, but ASP.NET didn't make it easy for me to do IoC when creating my own handler factory that needed to rely on built-in functionality.

**Edit 2:** Fixed the fully qualified type name to `System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory`. Fixed the assembly search from searching for `IHttpHandler` which is in `System.Web` to `WebService` which is in `System.Web.Services`. Let me know if you have any issues.

**Edit 3:** Sorry about this. I left out the `SecurityCritical` class they use, which you can do another way if you want, but I just copied straight from them when I did it. It is used to elevate and assert permissions, which is why you need *full trust*.

### Code

```
    static YourCodeHere()
    {
        PrivilegedCommand cmd = new PrivilegedCommand();
        SecurityCritical.ExecutePrivileged(new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted), new SecurityCritical.PrivilegedCallback(cmd.Execute));
        handlerFactory = cmd.Result;
    }

    private class PrivilegedCommand
    {
        public IHttpHandlerFactory Result = null;

        public void Execute()
        {
            Type handlerFactoryType = typeof(System.Web.Services.WebService).Assembly.GetType("System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory");
            Result = (IHttpHandlerFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(handlerFactoryType, true);
        }
    }

/// <summary>
/// Utility class to be used from within this assembly for executing security critical code 
/// NEVER EVER MAKE THIS PUBLIC!
/// </summary>
/// <author>Erich Eichinger</author>
internal class SecurityCritical
{
    internal delegate void PrivilegedCallback();

    [SecurityCritical, SecurityTreatAsSafe]
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    internal static void ExecutePrivileged(IStackWalk permission, PrivilegedCallback callback)
    {
        permission.Assert();
        try
        {
            callback();
        }
        finally
        {
            CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert();
        }
    }
}
```